# How to save screenshots captured running Lambda function on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have Lambda function that takes screenshot of pages it visits.
How do I make pictures be saved and where should I save them ?

s3bucket maybe?

Answer (score 0):

An AWS Lambda function runs code just like any other application.

You can access and save information however you wish, such as using a database or Amazon S3.

Yes, Amazon S3 would be an excellent place to store the screenshots, but **it really depends on what you wish to do with the screenshots *after* they are captured**. Think about how to store information about when/where the screenshots were captured, in addition to the screenshots themselves.

As to *how* to save them, take a look at the documentation for your preferred programming language.

For example: [S3 — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to get a screenshot just to see how the page is opened by Hadlees Chrome. I run function on Lambda that should click a HTML element. Locally it works perfect  but when on Lambda I get error: node is not HTML element. I dont know why that happen. Any idea?

Comment: Can you share a snippet of code and a name of a lib?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5DB4Qr
This is only click case. I am using puppeteer-lambda libary. node js..